# Is it possible to provide DAOs or Room database without Dagger Module

Tags: android, android-room, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

The *Room* persistence library defines databases to provide its `Dao`s.

```
@Database(...)
abstract class DbImpl : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val daoImpl: DaoImpl
}
```

How could I provide all DAOs in *Dagger*, without the need to provide these manually with a `Module`?

```
@Provides
fun provideDaoImpl(
    db: DbImpl,
) = db.daoImpl
```

Comment: if you are already providing your db, why not to create abstract functions inside DbImpl and call them using your db object

Comment: for the db you have to tell dagger how to provide it because you don't own the class

Comment: I'm providing `DbImpl`, but I would like to not provide all DAOs separately. Also I'm trying to not depend on the `DbImpl` directly. Otherwise `db.daoImpl` would be an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the Room database as a component dependency, thus implicitly provide any declared DAOs from it.

The benefit of this approach is that you **save some boilerplate as you don't need the `@Provides` methods** wrapping every DAO. The downside is that the Room database **now needs to be created along with your component** to link it as a dependency which may incur **unnecessary work at app-startup**.

I'd stick with the `@Provides` methods and the boilerplate module. Your DAOs hopefully don't change *that* much that this would be hard to maintain and it gives you the benefit of being able to create the database lazily when needed. Just make sure that you avoid scoping your DAO wrapper methods, as Room already does some internal double-locking.

Comment: what about Dagger hilt? Can't we get rid of module for database with Hilt?

Comment: I am facing with the same problem when create a database component which will be declared as dependency in ApplicationComponent, mean it will also create the DAOs object along with application scope. Do you have any idea to improve?

Another way I think is just provide the database instance in DatabaseComponent, and let the feature's component create and provide the DAOs it need itself. But I don't really like this way. I created a new module database to handle database jobs, but let the feature modules create DAOs itself, which doesn't make much sense to me.